# How to remove the line from html page of an angular application with multiple forms

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms

I have got this page but for some reason, I see a line in my page.
[image]

Here is the code

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="advanced" ng-hide="sync model">
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="" *ngFor="let options of syncOptionsList">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="checkbox abc-checkbox abc-checkbox-info">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{options.value}}" formControlName="{{options.value}}" [value]="options.value" (change)="options.value == 'inplace' ? inplaceCheckBoxHandler($event) : ''"
                    />
                    <label>{{ options.title }}</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
             <p>Include/Exclude Options</p>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-right" for="datacopy_file_in">Datacopy File In</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" formControlName="datacopy_file_in" placeholder="" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-right" for="sync_exclude_file">Sync Exclude File</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" formControlName="sync_exclude_file" placeholder="" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
  </div>
```

What can I do to make the line go away? I am taking the options using ngfor I used legend and fieldset but its of no avail.

Comment: Please add you'r code to http://stackblitz.com/

Comment: possibly because you are using `class="nav-tabs"` as bootstrap class it's main class `class="nav nav-tabs"` has that line property you need to add you more code here try finding it by `inspect element`

Comment: Try doing below change in the css file.

  .nav-tabs { 
    border-bottom: none;
 }

Comment: https://angular-otetqs.stackblitz.io